# Angular mat-datepicker with date mask

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I write custom datepicker input component imlements `ControlValueAccessor` in Angular5 using mat-datepicker.

**date-picker.component.html:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="value" (blur)="onBlur()">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker (selectedChanged)="onChange($event)" #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**date-picker.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, forwardRef, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'he-IL' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
    CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR
  ],
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input()
  required: boolean;

  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();

  innerValue: Date = new Date();

  //Placeholders for the callbacks which are later provided
  //by the Control Value Accessor
  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;


  //get accessor
  get value(): Date {
    return this.innerValue;
  };

  //set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(v: Date) {
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
    }
  }

  constructor(private adapter: DateAdapter<any>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.adapter.setLocale('he');
  }

  //Occured value changed from module
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = value;

      //invoke value change event
      this.change.emit(this.innerValue);
    }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  onChange(event) {
    this.value = event;
    this.onBlur();
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.onChangeCallback(this.innerValue);
    //invoke value change event
    this.change.emit(new Date(this.innerValue));
    //this.onTouchedCallback();
  }
}
```

I want to add ability to enforce date mask like `'dd/MM/yyyy'`

I found matching example, but it written in angularJS and md datepicker:

[Angular Material Datepicker and ngMask](https://codepen.io/_4zuko/pen/dMRXmj)

Any idea for implementation in Angular?

### Edit:

Attached live demo, Based on Vivek Doshi nice answer, This demo not work due to `[textMask]` attribute.

**[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-mask-undcrh?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html)**

Comment: When you say you want to enforce it, do you mean you want to force the user to write only a valid date, or do you just want to recognize dates as `dd/MM/YYYY` ?

Comment: I mean to enforce the valid format also to help user write correct date. (i will check the value before submit, but i didn't want that the user can write any text)

Comment: Well, if your really want to force it, you can disable the input and only enable the click on the calendar button, so that the user can only chose his date in the calendar

Comment: its good idea, but if the user want to set far date its not friendly, also, there are users that prefer keyboard versus mouse.

Comment: I agree. Maybe you could **[take a look at this example](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/)** ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can achieve that with the help of **[angular2-text-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask)**

**Component side :**

```
public mask = {
    guide: true,
    showMask : true,
    mask: [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/',/\d/, /\d/,/\d/, /\d/]
  };
```

**Template Side :**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [textMask]="mask" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-mask)**

Now all you need to do is bind the logic and validations ,

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-mask-ngmodel)** with the solution of `ControlValueAccessor`.

---

3rd Demo , with your code

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-mask-pending)**

Comment: Thank you!, its excellent and correct solution, but, in our project, We create a custom date component implements ControlValueAccessor, and angular2-text-mask reported a limitation (from NPM): "Unfortunately, we are unable to support Ionic 2 ion-input at this point as it overrides the ControlValueAccessor that Text Mask requires to perform its job.", Maybe you have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: @StackOverflow , please read this , https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/668 , it will work if you dont put  `ion-input` inside  `ion-item`.

Comment: I don't understand your solution, I modified the question and add my component code, I will be glad if you can give your attention again!

Comment: @StackOverflow, that was the answer of the limitation of `angular2-text-mask` , please create a stackblitz demo if possible , So I can help you more.

Comment: I attached live demo to my question, Based on your working demo, Now the demo not working due to this error: "More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute", Thanks a million!

Comment: @StackOverflow, you can solve that by change [(ngModel)] to (ngModelChange)

Comment: I try this in another stackblitz, not work tow way binding yet , see in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-mask-fbmxrj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @StackOverflow , please provide me last example in working without text-mask.

Comment: Correct :), mistake as result of partial copy paste... I fixed the demo and it works well without textMask, thanks.

Comment: @StackOverflow , please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-mask-pending

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now, I only add validation condition in your todate() method in order to handle invalid dates values (empty and etc).

Comment: @StackOverflow , Yeeessss atlast , Glad to here that , :D

Comment: @VivekDoshi How can I adapt this to work with Reactive Forms ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi How can I use your solution with Reactive forms instead of ngModel?
Any help would be appreciated! Ty!

Answer (score -3):

If i've understood your problem, why don't you try with a `pipe`? like this:

`"{{yourDateModel | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}"`

in your html `date-picker` component

Comment: This date pipe take care only of the date display. I want to enforce date input mask